# Python tkinter access data from a different class and frame

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am relatively new to Python programming and in the end want to create calculation GUIs for our department. Therefore I started working around with tkinter or customtkinter. My idea is to have one Main.py programm that configures the general structure of the App. Then I want to create some subfiles A and B with different classes to configure the subframes of the App. Therefore the code should be clearer to understand and other colleagues could implement their own frames/ideas more easily.

The Problem:
I have an entry box in class B that I need in class A. As an easy example in the calculation method of file A I want to summarize the entry of value_1 and value_2 but how to access value_2 in class A?

A.py

```
import customtkinter
import tkinter
from B import *

class A:
    def __init__(self, root, frame):
        self.root = root
        self.frame = frame


        self.value_1_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.frame, text="Value_1").place(x=20, y=150)
        self.value_1_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.frame)
        self.value_1_entry.place(x=120, y=150)

        self.berechnung_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame, text="Calculate", fg_color="#204A94", command=self.calculate)
        self.berechnung_button.place(x=20, y=700)

    def calculate(self):
        pass
```

B.py

```
import customtkinter
import tkinter

class B:
    def __init__(self, root, frame):

        self.root = root
        self.frame = frame

        self.value_2_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.frame, text="Value_2").place(x=20, y=170)
        self.value_2_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.frame)
        self.value_2_entry.place(x=120, y=170)
```

Main.py

```
import customtkinter
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from A import *
from B import *

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Main")
        self.geometry("1024x768")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.navigation_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, corner_radius=0, fg_color="#204A94")
        self.navigation_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.navigation_frame.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

        self.main_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.navigation_frame, text="Home",command=self.main_button_event)
        self.main_button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

        self.main_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.navigation_frame, text="A",command=self.A_button_event)
        self.main_button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

        self.general_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.navigation_frame, text="B",command=self.B_button_event)
        self.general_button.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ew")

        self.main_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, fg_color="transparent", corner_radius=0)
        self.main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.A_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, fg_color="transparent", corner_radius=0)
        self.A_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.cl_A = A(self, self.A_frame)

        self.B_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, fg_color="transparent", corner_radius=0)
        self.B_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.cl_B = B(self, self.B_frame)


    def select_frame_by_name(self, name):
        if name == "main":
            self.main_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        else:
            self.main_frame.grid_forget()
        if name == "A":
            self.A_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        else:
            self.A_frame.grid_forget()
        if name == "B":
            self.B_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        else:
            self.B_frame.grid_forget()


    def main_button_event(self):
        self.select_frame_by_name("main")

    def A_button_event(self):
        self.select_frame_by_name("A")

    def B_button_event(self):
        self.select_frame_by_name("B")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I tried to create a class instance in file A: self.cl_B = B(root, frame) and then use value_2 = self.cl_B.value_2_entry.get() but the class instance just showing me the frame of file B in frame A.

Comment: You could use shared Tkinter `textvariable`s instead of needing to do `.get()`.

Comment: Why don't you just use the instance `cl_B` already created in `App`?

Comment: In the Main.py file I can easily access the value_2_entry of file B but how can I submit this value to file A then?

Comment: Since `A` has a reference to `App`: `self.root`, so you can use `self.root.cl_B.value_2_entry.get()` to get the value.